# How can I put the android studio on the applications?

Tags: android-studio

I have a question, I just installed Android Studio from official site, but, after it installation been conclude, it appears in no place. I can't find it to launch.

Comment: What was the exact name of the item you installed?

Comment: How did you install it? Android Studio should appear in the applications list like any other graphical application.